# program that checks for array

Tags: c#

I am making a little program in C# that checks if input is an arithmetic array or a normal array.

The problem is when I make a for loop that checks if the array is arithmetic, I lose the last two elements off the array because i had to reduce `numbers.Length` with 2, otherwise I would get an error saying its out of bounds. (btw., arithmetic is for example: 2 - 4 - 6 - 8 - 10 - 12, so +2 every time)

```cs
int[] numbers = new int[6];

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Give a number: ");
    numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}

bool boolArithmetic = false;
bool boolNormal = false;
int counterArithmetic = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 2; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i] == numbers[i + 2] - numbers[i + 1])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arithmetic Array");
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        counterArithmetic++;
        boolArithmetic = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Normal Array");
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        boolNormal = true;
    }
}

if (counterArithmetic == 6 && boolArithmetic)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ARITHMETIC ARRAY");
}
else if (boolNormal)
{
    Console.WriteLine("NORMAL ARRAY");
}
```

I tried adding +2 to the array but this didn't work at all. I also tried a do while loop but it just confused me even more.

Does someone know how to fix this so that my code work fine?

Comment: `-3` instead of `-2` in for loop

Comment: I don't see how you can expect `counterArithmetic` to go to 6 as you're not iterating the loop 6 times for an array of 6 elements.

Comment: Also break out of the loop when you set `boolNormal`. Also don't have two books: `boolArithmetic` is simply `!boolNormal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't lose the last two elements.
In the body of the loop you check the `i+1` and `i+2` elements.

Why do you use a counter to count how many pairs have the same difference? Just use a single boolean flag. As soon as you see a difference that doesn't match, set the flag to true and break out of the loop.

```
bool isArithmetic = true;
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 2; i++)
{
   if (numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i] != numbers[i + 2] - numbers[i + 1])
   {
       isArithmetic = false;
       break;
   }
}
```

Now, just check the bool `isArithmetic` to figure out what to print:

```
if (isArithmetic)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ARITHMETIC ARRAY");
} 
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("NORMAL ARRAY");
}
```

This assumes your array has at least 3 elements. Arrays with less than 3 elements will always be considered "arithmetic arrays" by this logic, since the for loop is never entered.

Comment: thank you so much! this is a very good solution! Btw if i wanted to add another else if statement to check if the given input is a geometric array, arithmetic array or a normal array what would i have to add? I tried adding a second bool for the geometric and an else if statement else if (numbers[i + 1] / numbers[i] != numbers[i + 2] / numbers[i + 1]), but it failed .

Comment: Do you have a break in your else if? Since progressions will rarely be both arithmetic and geometric, your code will trigger either the first or the second break, resulting in possibly the wrong answer. One solution could be to simply loop over the array again, this time checking for geometric progression. Can you come up with some logic to handle everything in a single loop, think about how you want your program to flow, and draw a flowchart if you need a visual aid. @laboonx

Comment: If you aren't able to figure something out, you can ask another question with a [mre], and I'd be happy to take a look

Answer (score 0):

The condition inside the second `for` loop should be changed, it should be `i < numbers.Length - 3` instead of `i < numbers.Length - 2`.

If you are checking for arithmetic array, you can actually do the following:

1. Compute the difference between first two elements, let call it pre-computed difference.
2. Then starting from third element, calculate the difference of each consecutive terms, lets call it current difference.
3. Check if the current difference is equal to the pre-computed difference.If not break, and conclude that the array is not arithmetic
4. Keep on iterating, till you visit the entire array. If you have visited the entire array, then its arithmetic.

```cs
int preComputedDiff = numbers[1]-numbers[0];
for(int i = 1;i < numbers.Length -1;i++){
    int currDiff = numbers[i+1] - numbers[i];
    if(currDiff != preComputedDiff){
                    Console.WriteLine("Normal Array");
                    break;
     }
}
 Console.WriteLine("ARITHMETIC ARRAY");
```

Although you have to add the constraints of the array to make the code more suitable.

Comment: Not quite. You need to break the loop if you print "normal" because then the array _can't_ be "arithmetic", and there's no point checking the rest. Also only print "arithmetic" if you didn't break out

Comment: Also you never test `numbers[2]-numbers[1]`

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the arithmetic test into another method. This allows you to separate console input/output from the logic

```cs
private static bool IsArithmetic(int[] a)
{
    if (a.Length < 3) {
        return false;
    }
    int delta = a[1] - a[0];
    for (int i = 2; i < a.Length; i++) {
        if (a[i] - a[i - 1] != delta) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

It is easier to first compute the difference between the two first elements and to reuse it to compare it with the difference between the remaining elements instead of always comparing 3 elements.

Whether a sequence of 0, 1 or two terms is considered to be an arithmetic progression seems not to be clearly defined. See: [Minimum number of terms in an arithmetic progression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2823856/minimum-number-of-terms-in-an-arithmetic-progression).

Tests:

```cs
int[] a1 = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 }; // Yes +2
int[] a2 = { 2, 4, 6, 9, 10, 12 }; // No, deviation in the middle
int[] a3 = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 13 }; // No, deviation at the end
int[] a4 = { 1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 }; // No, deviation at the beginning
int[] a5 = { 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 }; // No, deviation at the beginning
int[] a6 = { 3, 6, 9, 12, 15 };    // Yes +3
int[] a7 = { 3, 8 };               // No, too short
int[] a8 = { 2, 5, 6, 8, 10, 12 }; // No, deviation at index = 1
int[] a9 = { 2, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12 }; // No, deviation at index = 2

Console.WriteLine($"Is a1 arithmetic: {(IsArithmetic(a1) ? "yes" : "no")}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is a2 arithmetic: {(IsArithmetic(a2) ? "yes" : "no")}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is a3 arithmetic: {(IsArithmetic(a3) ? "yes" : "no")}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is a4 arithmetic: {(IsArithmetic(a4) ? "yes" : "no")}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is a5 arithmetic: {(IsArithmetic(a5) ? "yes" : "no")}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is a6 arithmetic: {(IsArithmetic(a6) ? "yes" : "no")}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is a7 arithmetic: {(IsArithmetic(a7) ? "yes" : "no")}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is a8 arithmetic: {(IsArithmetic(a8) ? "yes" : "no")}");
Console.WriteLine($"Is a9 arithmetic: {(IsArithmetic(a9) ? "yes" : "no")}");
```

prints:

```
Is a1 arithmetic: yes
Is a2 arithmetic: no
Is a3 arithmetic: no
Is a4 arithmetic: no
Is a5 arithmetic: no
Is a6 arithmetic: yes
Is a7 arithmetic: no
Is a8 arithmetic: no
Is a9 arithmetic: no
```

These tests ensure that the logic covers the whole index range.

Answer (score 0):

just modify your code like this, just iterate and check until the number in index 5 then ur done no need to print arthimetic array or normal array in every iteration. and finally check for the count variable and `numbers.Length-1` that is how far u can increment the count variable if it is arthimetic array.

```
int[] numbers = new int[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Give a number: ");
            numbers[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        int counterArithmetic = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i <=numbers.Length-2; i++)
        {
            if ((numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i]) == 2)
            {
                counterArithmetic+=1;

            }
        }

        if (counterArithmetic == numbers.Length-1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ARITHMETIC ARRAY");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("NORMAL ARRAY");
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).